# How to make sure that ignoring members in AutoMapper does not set values to null?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have this code:

```
var variants = CreateMap<TechDataVariant, TechData>();
variants.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
variants.ForPath(dest => dest.Acceleration.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Acceleration.Label))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Acceleration.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Acceleration.Value))
```

I first ignore all props and then map them.

I do this for 3 objects where I have 3 sources for Techdata so it could look like this:

```
var other1 = CreateMap<Other1, TechData>();
other1.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

other1.ForPath(dest => dest.Other1.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.SomethingElse1.Label))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Other1.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.SomethingElse2.Value))
```

and third:

```
var other2 = CreateMap<Other2, TechData>();
other2.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

other2.ForPath(dest => dest.Other2.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.SomethingElse2.Label))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Other2.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.SomethingElse2.Value))
```

I then have a object and a dto where I map these and use `AfterMap`:

```
CreateMap<MyDTO, MyTarget>()
           .ForMember...some props

           .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
             {
                 if (dest.TechData == null)
                     dest.TechData = new TechData();

                 // Map the individual source types to TechData using context.Mapper.Map
                 var variant = context.Mapper.Map<TechData>(src.TechDataVariant);
                 var other1 = context.Mapper.Map<TechData>(src.other1);
                 var other2 = context.Mapper.Map<TechData>(src.other2);

                 // set values on dest target
             });
```

**Problem**

On the `AfterMap`, I can see that `src.TechDataVariant` has values. But as soon as this is done:

```
var variant = context.Mapper.Map<TechData>(src.TechDataVariant);
```

all values in `variant` are `null`.

I have figured out that it is due to

```
variants.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But how would I fix this?

Manual mapping works but the problem is that for every mapped object I would manualy need to write ignores for same fields multiple times or in one scenario I would use 2 but ignore 20 and in another it would be the other way arround and in a third a mix etc. From a maintenance and code quality perspective becomes an issue. Thise is due to that I have multiple sources for the same target.

How can I accomplish this in a good way?

EDIT:

To clarify why this is a problem for me:

If I do this :

```
.ForPath(dest => dest.MyPop, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

And I Do it for one of the mappings but in another I map it.

Imagine this scenario but In my case I have 3 mappings and 20 fields.

In mapping one I map 15 fields and ignore 5.
In mapping 2 I map 2 fields and ignore 18.

In map 3 I map 5 and ignore 15.

Now note the fields that are being ignored are not the same in all mappings.
This is why the "IgnoreAllUnMapped" becomse a feature of necessity. Essential what I am trying to do is keep values of `src.techDataVariant`(example) even efter I run the "Ignore"

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Would you mind presenting a code answer? im a bit foggy on how to apply it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to replace `ForAllMembers` by `ForAllOtherMembers` but the library author decided to remove that method since the v11.0

Answer (score -2):

Alternative approach is to create mapping method and map it "manually"

> - No configuration required
> - **Supports all possible logic and conversions**
> - Easy to read
> - Comprehensible for developers with different expertise level
> - Compile-time type checking
> - Doesn't require mocking when testing

```cs
public static TechDataVariant MapVariantData(TechData source)
{
    return new TechDataVariant 
    {
        // add mapping logic here
    };
}

// Usage
var variant = MapVariantData(src.TechDataVariant);
```

Comment: This would still force me to have 3 methods , one for every source and then add diffirent ignores in each method. I would still need to maintain it

Comment: For more than a few properties this doesn't sound like a solution.

Comment: This correct approach for any number of properties. Notice that Automapper was designed to map properties with same name (plus a feature to flatten nested object structure into flat one). 
If you do more than that, as in OP's case, then you will be forced to "dig" into Automapper docs :)

Comment: @CodingLittle you need to maintain code in both cases, with Automapper or without. Scenario without Auttomapper **Supports all possible logic and conversions**, plus performance will be much better than with Automapper ;)

Comment: The propeerties do have the same names, as you can see in the code. Of course AM would help is this case. As with any tool, there's a learning curve. But writing dumb code by hand should not be acceptable in any code base.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, you don't need to write code for mapping, instead you can use source generators to generate the code for you, which will be compiled. 
Notice that by using Automapper you are moving compile time problem into the runtime. Loosing on compile time feedback and performance as well.

Comment: That's a different mapper :) AM has configuration validation to compensate and the small performance hit is insignificant for most. But clearly a mapper with source generation helps. That's not manual mapping.